# Xamarin crash file @ xamarin_get_block_descriptor

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash-reports

I am new to iOS Crash debugging but I managed to find the crash file and and symbolicate it (I think? I pressed the button in any case). Here is the thread that crashed info. It occurs occasionally on the load of one specific view:

[image: Crash Report]

The view initializes the view model and starts a timer:

```
  InitializeComponent();
  var vm = new OpenBatchesViewModel();
  this.BindingContext = vm;

  Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>{ some code here})
```

and the view model calls out to an API for some data:

```
public OpenBatchesViewModel()
{
   SearchString = string.Empty;
   CutOff = RemitStationApiService.GetCutOffTime().Result;
   Username = RemitStationApiService.GetUsername();
   _openBatches = RemitStationApiService.GetOpenBatches().Result.ToList();

   CurrentBatchList = new ItemObservableCollection<OpenBatch>(_openBatches);            
   CurrentBatchList.ItemPropertyChanged += _currentBatchList_ItemPropertyChanged;
   OpenContextMenuCommand = new Command<OpenBatch>(batch => BatchButtonClick(batch));
   Activity = false;

 }
```

The view model implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

TIA

Comment: have you attempted to add any exception handling or crash logging to your code?  That would be a lot more useful than the iOS crash log

Answer (score 0):

Check out Microsoft AppCenter's diagnostic abilities to track crashes.